# Can I leave my bags somewhere in or near Guangzhou airport?

Tags: luggage, china, guangzhou

An upcoming trip of mine will have a 20 hour layover in Guangzhou. I'd like to spend that time exploring the city without my bags, but I don't have any place to leave them.

Is there any place in or around the airport where I can leave my bags?

Comment: be aware, GZ is huge huge huge !

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search for 'left luggage Guangzhou airport' gives [this](http://www.baiyunairport.com/en/web/guest/lkfw/jcss/luggage_office) as the first result.

There are six locations around the airport where you can leave luggage for an hourly or daily rate depending on size. The offices are open from 6am to 10pm daily.

The web site linked above gives locations, costs and service hours and a contact phone number.